# Extending hibernate entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have 2 PostgresSQL tables: posts and messages with following structures:

**posts:**

- post_id - serial PK
- title
- ...other fields

**messages:**

- message_id - serial PK
- post_id - int reference posts(post_id)
- text
- ...other fields

and correspoding entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "messages")
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "message_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private String postId;
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;
}
```

I created 2 repositories for that entities, but I also want to get entending entity:

```
@Entity
public class PostExtra extends Post {
    int messagesCount;
}
```

with SELECT and GROUP BY query, etc I dont want to save PostExtra to database.

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("...", TicketExtra.class);
return q.getResultList();
```

I got an exception - ERROR: column ticket0_.messages_count does not exist. 
How can I fix that?